# Using cucumber with selenium

Tags: cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I am planning to use cucumber with selenium webdriver in ruby. I have seen that its possible in java. can someone guide me on a tutorial? how to use annotations, what has to be there in the cucumber etc. A simple example would be great

Comment: See [new Cucumber website](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Cucumber with Java/Junit in my project. 
Info at the following link is particularly useful:
http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/cucumber-jvm-with-cucumber-java-cucumber-junit-example/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using directly selenium webdriver with cucumber: use capybara which is cleaner ,simple and high -level API on top of selenium webdriver.Capabara has the advantage over selenium that other drivers can also be plugged in if required for other testing needs.

Cabybara can be installed as usual gem from command prompt:
**gem install capybara** which also includes selenium -webdriver as dependent gem.